# How can I obtain a JSON from a restful API in Angular?

Tags: angular, rest, http, endpoint

Im learning angular, trying to consume the JSON info from this restfullAPI:

[https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode/{callingcode}](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode/%7Bcallingcode%7D)

It shows a list of countries and its information...

There are 300 countries in the REST list...

I need to navigate througt each "{callingcode}" but some of them return error 404 cause there is no information in it...

How can i hande this error and keep the for loop going ?

Also i dont know if the arrow function sintax whitin the subscribe method is correct

This is what i have

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Pais } from 'src/app/entities/pais';


@Component({
selector: 'app-connector',
templateUrl: './connector.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./connector.component.css']
})

export class ConnectorComponent implements OnInit {

paises: Pais[] = [];

constructor(public http:HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getCountries();
}

getCountries(){
for(let i=0; i<=300; i++ ){ 
  
  return this.http.get<Pais[]>("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode" + i).subscribe(
    paises => {this.paises = paises
    console.log(this.paises)
    })
 }
}}
```

Comment: As for your subscription method you are missing a `;`  at the closing tag

Comment: instead of calling api 300 times, call it once https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/

Comment: @Nonik is right, don't call 300 times just get all of them at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all**

You need to push into paises the sum of 300 responses, your code are overwriting with the last.
And remove return!

```
   this.http.get<Pais[]>("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode" + i).subscribe(
        paises => {
          this.paises.push(paises)
          console.log(this.paises)
        },
        error => { console.error(error)
       });
```

I were you I would do this in a service so as to share data between components through DependencyInjection

Arrow function is good

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.

1. Pipe the request with [rxjs Merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge)
2. Simply remove that `return` keyword in the for-loop. Let paise be assigned when the request goes through and the failed request paise should be null.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forkJoin` & `catchError` to handle 404 error

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  var codes = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    codes.push(i);
  }

  forkJoin(codes.map(c => this.getData(c)))
    .pipe(
      map(e => e.filter(d => !!d)),
      tap(results => console.log("Results", results))
    )
    .subscribe();
}

getData(code: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http
    .get<any>(
      "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode/" + code.toString()
    )
    .pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 404) {
          return of(null);
        } else {
          throwError(err);
        }
      })
    );
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vg2yzq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)